# Accessibility within video settings to reduce chances of seizures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, accessibility

I've been playing Minecraft (Java) for a while now, survival and creative, but sometimes the visuals that occur within the game as a glitch causes me to get a migraine.

The visuals I'm talking about are things that happen generally in creative mode with commands or command blocks in use. I had a case where I used a command block to replace blocks around me with air as I walked around, but at the time I was underground and came to a location where breaking the block would have water come flowing in from outside. If I didn't have the command block in use, then I would have easily been able to replace the block again so water would stop flowing, but since I was far from the command block, I just stood there and watched the flashes appearing as the block next to me changed between water and air. Some people may not be bothered by this, but some might, and I definitely was since I'm epileptic.

My question is asking if there are any settings as of now that would reduce the chance of that happening, or the visuals of that appearing in a different way? Otherwise, I will bring it up to the developers to consider a solution to that or players may end up getting hurt.

Comment: while there are plenty of accessibility options in the game to turn down screenshake or nausea distortion, there is nothing to "smoothen block placement" or "water expansion", especially not with commandblocks involved. Water flows. Commandblocks remove flowed water. You can of course try to reach out to the devs through the feedback website, and while they are usually very big on accessibility, I could imagine that they classify commandblocks as "use at your own risk" kind of things.